# Export unmanaged C# DLL (with namespace) for MT4

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces, unmanaged, metatrader4

I have a code in **`C#`**, this code should be export as unmaged code because it will be used by <kbd>**MetaTrader Terminal 4**</kbd> as an `#import`-ed library ( **`.dll`** ).

> **The big questions are:**
>   **`Q1 )`** Can I use `system.net` and `system.net.mail` namespaces for export as unmanaged `DLL`?
>   **`Q2 )`** If not, what is a better solution for this ( export `DLL` as unmanaged and with a reference to namespaces ) ?
>   **`Q3 )`** Why export does not work for this function (EnviarCorreo)?

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
namespace Testme
{
    class Test
    {
        [DllExport("EnviarCorreo", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public static int EnviarCorreo(string ServidorSMTP, string usuario, string pass, bool HTML, string Asunto, string Cuerpo, string Desde, string Para)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        //direccion desde
        mail.From = new MailAddress("tester@domain.com", "Name");
        mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("info@domain.com");
        MailAddress toa = new MailAddress("admin@domain.com");

        string contenido = "Aquí vamos a escribir en HTML <br>Para ver</br>";
        mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        mail.To.Clear();
        mail.To.Add(toa);
        mail.Subject = "PRUEBA DE CORREO";
        mail.Body = contenido;// +Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com");
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("tester@domain.com", "blabla");
        smtp.Send(mail);
        return 158;
    }

        [DllExport("Add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int Add(int left, int right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }

        [DllExport("Sub", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int Sub(int left, int right)
        {
            return left - right;
        }

        [DllExport("AddDouble", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static double AddDouble(double left, double right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }

        [DllExport("AddFloat", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static float AddFloat(float left, float right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Export doesnt work` is not a good explanation. Please elaborate.

Comment: Also you should really specify exactly what your `DllExport` is. It is not standard, and it could be [this](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) or anything else.

Comment: 1: Yes. 2: N/A  3: you don't know because nobody catches the exception when the CLR can't find your dll or the marshaller keels over on your bad declaration or the method throws an exception.  You'll have to change the Debugger Type from Auto to Mixed so you can at least diagnose the most basic mishaps.  And use try/catch-em-all in your code so you can return an error code.

Comment: Hello Hans, about "1: Yes", do you know how can I do this (linked namespace while export as unmanaged DLL)? You are right, I'm adding try-catch for see any error because at this moment I dont have any error and it is very strange because this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

.Net is a managed language so you can't just create an unmanaged dll. It's slightly more complicated since your dll depends on the framework.  There are ways to do it but they require a bit of work.  Take a look at the answers to this post.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afb244b3-1cd4-48b4-93ba-f019fdce6a8e/creating-an-unmanaged-dll-in-c?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Hi, the big questions is, Can I export managed function to unmanaged code if I have namespace from Framework? Do you have others tips?